# Anyone Know How To Create A Developer Portal On GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working on GCP trying to create an API gateway and first I created a gateway using API Gateway and then I created a gateway using Endpoints. However I couldn’t figure out how to create a developer portal using API Gateway and Endpoints says that the developer portal is deprecated.

So my question is does anyone know how to create a developer portal using either of these services on GCP?

Comment: It should be a feature of API Gateway (it's no longer one on Cloud Endpoint) but I guess there is some delay in the release. So, for nom, there is nothing :(

Comment: What a letdown. Why would they take away the portal for endpoints with no replacement in place? This comes standard for Azure and AWS.

Comment: True. There was movement in the team. I think it's only delay, or a lack of priorisation on that product. Keep in mind that the Google Cloud API Gateway flagship is Apigee. And the position of the API Gateway is not really clear outside and inside Google Cloud.

Comment: Funny you'd mention Apigee, which I think it is overpriced (from what I see on message boards and what not) I still tried to use it and cannot even do that without first talking to a sales rep. Whats even funnier is that I applied to talk to a sales rep about a week ago and never received a response or a call.

Comment: Apigee is more and more integrated to Google Cloud but it's an heavy thing that I don't really understand the cost/advantage ratio for now...